# Difficult IQ test question: What is the box suggesting?

Tags: pattern, visual

I found a [Very Difficult IQ Test](http://www.allthetests.com/quiz18/quiz/1139060031/Very-Difficult-IQ-Test) on web.
One of its questions is:

> What is the box suggesting?
>
> [image]

I have seen the answer but there was no clues for the logic behind that.

> 1. 123456789
> 2. 176h54308
> 3. 627456934
> 4. 126485704
> 5. 673258719

**What is the logic?**

The solution is the

> first option (**123456789**)

from the list above.

Comment: If you're looking to understand why the solution is the way it is, it may be more beneficial to add the solution so we have as much information to work with as possible. If this isn't your primary goal, though, then no worries!

Comment: source and answer added to question description.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm not certain this is the complete (or even right) answer.

All little symbols in the perimeter squares (disregard the middle one for now) point to the next square, going counterclockwise. Starting from the upper left,
these symbols are the top half (without centre bar) of the digital representations of the digits 1 through 8. The square in the middle is a 9 with the top and bottom quarter missing, as indicated by the 'X'.

None of the other sequences have the correct digital representations to fit the given upper halves: of the symbols in the given sequences, only '1' fits the top left, which provides a starting point to check each sequence.

Comment: what do you mean by "all little symbols point to the next square"? I did not get that. also, if there is such a point to next square, why should we go counter-clockwise?

Comment: With "point to" I mean they are attached to the side you have to cross to get to the next square. Meaning from upper left, you go down, down, right, right, etc, which completes a CCW cycle. I have no idea why the 8 doesn't "point" down though.

Comment: i see. but what about the order of numbers? i can see 7 in third position of sequence and 4 should be the 7th character

Comment: btw. it is not a good question for IQ test. it is only difficult to understand. +1

Answer (score 28):

I figured adding a picture will more clearly explain [the accepted answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/2283/19765#2286). With this image, one can clearly see the 123456789. The parts marked in red are where you were expected to extrapolate.

[image]